# Best practice regarding helpers of JS class (place in or out of class)?

Tags: javascript, performance, garbage-collection

I've recently had some performance and memory management issues with a mapbox application displaying large amounts of data (the browser would crash after ~20h from accumulating too much garbage - a public, highly visible, completely automated machine and refresh was never required by design). While the problem turned out to be strictly related to how mapbox handles rendering and animations and it's more or less fixed, it did make me wonder if there are any places where I could improve the application's performance and memory management.

Which raises the following question:

I have a singleton class (a service), injected into multiple components.

Inside this class, I have multiple helper methods which could be external to the singleton but from an application's logic, they belong to the service (they're not currently used anywhere else). Admittedly, they might be used in other components if the app logic changes.

**Is it better to declare the helpers inside the class or outside of it?** If it depends on certain factors, which are those factors?

I could do:

```
const helperA = () => stuff

export class MyClass {
  // ... methods/constructor where I use helperA()
}
```

obviously, the helper(s) could be placed in another file and imported, but that's irrelevant.

Or I could do

```
export class MyClass {
  private helperA = () => stuff;
  // ... methods/constructor where I use this.helperA()
}
```

I'm tempted to place `helperA` outside of the class. It's probably a better principle since, in case the app logic changes and I'll need it elsewhere, helperA is ready for export, without the need to instantiate the class.

I realize this can be regarded as a design preference.
However, I'm more interested in the technical aspects. I want to know if there is any advantage or disadvantage of doing it one way or the other before I decide where to place the helper(s).

They are presented schematically here but there might be a significant amount of helpers and some of them might be used on large collections of data and performance is an important aspect here, and so is memory management (garbage collection) (i.e: are externally defined constants garbage collected when the class instance is deleted? My wild guess is they aren't, because they're needed in case another member of the class is instantiated. But another wild guess is that it's irrelevant, because the class is a singleton).

Comment: The class is a singleton? Why a class then? And constants stay forever.

Comment: @Jonas, a fairly good question. Because that's what made sense when I initially coded it. It's also because it's an Angular app and all Angular services (at least in the docs) are classes. Now that you've asked, I realized I'd have probably used an object if it was a Vue app. I frankly don't see any advantage out of it being a class but, on the other hand, I'm probably not going to change it. It would raise too much code reviews debates inside the team and I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: @Jonas. Ref: "constants stay forever". Please define *"forever"*.  A very peculiar aspect of trying to fix the initial bug is that when we tried to refresh the app (say, by using `window.location`), the browser would not release the memory. It only did so when we used *"Empty cache and hard reload"*, which required manual intervention. However, it turned out to be a known mapbox issue which was fixed in `1.5.0` and upgrading + removing the map and replacing it with a new instance every few hours worked. It now no longer garbage collects - already 4 days into it, without restarting it.

Comment: That's interesting ... Do you have a link to the mapbox issue?

Comment: *forever* in the sense of *as long as the tab exists* or *as long as the nodejs process runs*

Comment: The relevant issues where: [#8913](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8913), [#8813](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8813) and [#8850](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8850). 8913 being the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few tests I've run in Chrome (which interests me the most):
I've run each test at least 3 times and result times are consistent.

a) helpers inside, called **2 × 1e7** times on **1e3 class instances**: `132170.80500000156` (> 2 minutes)

```js
const t0 = performance.now();

class MyClass {
  value = 0;
  up = l => l + 1;
  down = l => l - 1;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      this.up(this.value);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      this.down(this.value);
    }
  }
}
let a;
for (let i = 0; i < 1e3; i++) {
  a = new MyClass();
}
console.log({
  duration: performance.now() - t0
});
```

b) helpers outside, called **2 × 1e7** times for **1e3 class instances**: `5935.109999991255` (< 6 seconds)

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
const up = l => l + 1;
const down = l => l - 1;
class MyClass {
  value = 0;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      up(this.value);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      down(this.value);
    }
  }
}
let a;
for (let i = 0; i < 1e3; i++) {
  a = new MyClass();
}
console.log({
  duration: performance.now() - t0
});
```

c) helpers inside, called **2 × 1e10** times on **1 class instance**: `21271.935000026133` (> 20 seconds)

```js
const t0 = performance.now();

class MyClass {
  value = 0;
  up = l => l + 1;
  down = l => l - 1;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
      this.up(this.value);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
      this.down(this.value);
    }
  }
}
let a = new MyClass();

console.log({
  duration: performance.now() - t0
});
```

d) helpers outside, called **2 × 1e10** times for **1 class instance**: `21521.570000011707` (> 20 seconds)

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
const up = l => l + 1;
const down = l => l - 1;
class MyClass {
  value = 0;

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
      up(this.value);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
      down(this.value);
    }
  }
}
let a = new MyClass();
console.log({
  duration: performance.now() - t0
});
```

In each test the helpers are called the same amount of times.

My conclusion, as far as **performance** goes, is that it's irrelevant where you put the helpers in a singleton. When dealing with multiple instances it becomes relevant and it's better to place them outside.

---

In terms of **memory allocation** my results are inconclusive. None of the methods seems to be allocating significantly more memory or to accumulate significant amounts of garbage over time.